# embedding python program on a web server and connecting to it through Mobile App

Tags: android, python-3.x, webserver

I am currently working on an app for android devices. However, the application is too big to build for the device. Therefore, i want to build the core of the application (the part that does most of the work) and place it on a server, and build the light weight part of the application for the mobile device. The App on the android device is to connect to the application on the server, and collect the processed information. I want to build the application that is to run on a server with the Python language, as the application I'm working on does a lot of numeric crunching. Is this possible? If so, how can i embed my Python script to a web server and how to link it to my application

Comment: Look at something like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) (which is a python based webserver which you can easily use to serve things as needed, without needing anything else), and then use HTTP to send data back and forth, eg with Android's HttpUrlConnection classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server side I would suggest looking the [Flask framework](http://flask.pocoo.org/) (you may find the [Flask-Restful framework](http://flask-restful-cn.readthedocs.org/en/0.3.5/) and having the mobile app accessing it via a REST API. This may be useful depending on your Android experience: http://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html However, if you are doing a lot of number crunching, you may need to use WebSockets to connect the two and run your processing in a background thread. In which case I would look at http://www.elabs.se/blog/66-using-websockets-in-native-ios-and-android-apps and https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.org/

Comment: Thank-you. Is it possible to use the REST API with Django

Comment: Of course. [http://www.django-rest-framework.org/](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) might be useful.